# Codeigniter Datamapper - Add tablename by __construct

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

In my CMS I want to add modules by creating a table in the database. But Codeigniter with datamappers has one mandatory rule: give the tablename in your code. I have create a Datamapper model as following:

```
class Module_universeel extends DataMapper {

    public $table = 'module_universeel';
    public $has_one = array('page');

    public function __construct($module_table=null) {

        parent::__construct();
        if(isset($module_table)) $this->table = $module_table;

    }
}
```

This works when I create a table with the name: 'module_universeel'. When I change the tablename into 'module_news' or something, it works. But it doesn't change the structure ($this->fields) of my datamapper.

How can I do this? Does anybody have experience with this?

Answer (score 1):

Datamapper caches table definitions, controlled by the configuation property "production_cache".

If cache is enabled, the table will not be queried on every pageload, but the cached information is used.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `this->fields` array gets filled in the `parent::__construct();` And at that point the table name would still be `module_universeel`

Try this:

```
if(isset($module_table)) $this->table = $module_table;
parent::__construct();
```

Comment: That doesn't work either. It doesn't change the name of my table (when I print it).

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution. I add this to my datamapper model:

```
    public function updateTableFields(){
            $this->fields = array();
            $data_fields = $this->db->field_data($this->table);
            foreach ($data_fields as $data_field){
                $this->fields[] = $data_field->name;
                $this->stored->{$data_field->name} = "";
            }

        }
```

And I added this to my constructor:

$this->updateTableFields();

And now I changed the structure succesfully. Thanks for helping me!